# How to open an image with CImg?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cimg

I know this topic is answered in different places, but I can't get it to work.
First I tried to use the jpeglib library, the most complete tutorial for the installation, it had about 15 steps, the third I couldn't go any further. After installing ImageMagick, I also did not understand how to do it, nor what I did solved my problem.
I have Windows 10, and I program C ++ in QT Creator.

I will thank you for helping me, I know that you are almighty programmers, and that it bothers you to answer simple questions and even more if they are repeated. But please help me.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oJeh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CImg: Failed to recognize the jpg format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390318/cimg-failed-to-recognize-the-jpg-format)

Comment: no, i can't install libjpeg library, and i have ImageMagick installed but it doesn't work either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CImg with jpeglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373067/cimg-with-jpeglib)

Comment: I think the accepted answer, option 2, should solve your problem.

Comment: ohh my god, you were right, I had not understood correctly, it is so easy, option 2 is super simple

Comment: this is the first time this site really helps me, very grateful

Comment: I think the problem in most cases is the question and not the site. Ask a good question and you'll get very good answers very fast. Ask a bad, duplicated question without [mcve], without necessary information, without showing your efforts, and people can't or won't help. Read your question again and imagine someone would ask you this. How could you help with this few information? Compare your question to the question in the links.

Comment: You are great, but my other questions, although they may still be repeated, I do not understand the solutions and they just tell me this is repeated and they close the question is not fair. Not all of us understand a person's the solution, and there is not always a solution. And in many cases it is not even well explained. But you are great, thank you.

Comment: Most forums and sites have their own rules. The rules of this website is that you shouldn't ask duplicate questions. If you don't understand an answer write a comment under the answer and ask for clarification. If you think that your question is different make clear the differences. Your question has to be answerable without asking you for details. If you're missing necessary information your question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like this post [CImg with jpeglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373067/cimg-with-jpeglib) suggested by [Thomas Sablik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4645334/thomas-sablik). Installing ImageMagick is very simple, you just have to select the options that are in the image
[installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgvQp.png) during the ImageMagick installation. Excellent help, very grateful.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. The other answer is detailed and complete. This answer makes it more difficult to find the correct answer. This question should be closed as duplicate without answer.